# Domination relationship between generalized Dyck Paths

Tags: co.combinatorics, catalan-numbers

In short, we are seeking an injection between generalized Dyck paths that end at a certain height into the set of paths of the same length that end at a lower height such that the image path stays below the original path.

Let $\Gamma_{k,n}$ be the set of all length $n$ random walk paths (consisting of steps $(i,j) \to (i+1,j+1)$ and $(i,j) \to (i+1,j-1)$) started at $(0,0)$, ending at $(n,k)$, that never have negative $y$ coordinate. For example, $\Gamma_{0,2n}$ consists of the Dyck paths of length $2n$.

It is our intuition that for any $k$ and $n$ it holds that $|\Gamma_{k+2,n}| \leq |\Gamma_{k,n}|$. Moreover, since the ending point is lower, there ought to be an injection $i\colon \Gamma_{k+2,n} \to \Gamma_{k,n}$ such that the image $i(\gamma)$ is always "below" the starting path $\gamma \in \Gamma_{k+2,n}$. Formally, each $y$-coordinate of  $i(\gamma)$ is less than or equal to the $y$-coordinate of $\gamma$ with the same $x$-coordinate.

Here is a picture of what we mean by the image path being below the original. The dashed line is the part of the image that disagrees with the original path.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\Gamma_{2,4} $ has size 3 but $\Gamma_{0,4}$ has size 2. More generally, most paths that stay nonnegative for $n$ steps end at height of order square root of $n$.   Are you really looking for a coupling rather than an injection?